Does this allude to MacArthur's words?
From John Le Carré's Smiley's People:

But safe flats, unlike old generals, never die, he thought. They don’t even fade away.

Does that allude to MacArthur's famous words "Old soldiers never die--they just fade away" ?

The phrase Old soldiers never die, they simply fade away is fairly well-known in Britain without any specific reference to Gen. MacArthur (which I for one was unaware of). I think its origins in a soldiers' song are largely forgotten, and the expression is remembered mainly because of the humorous variants such as "Old pilots never die, they just go to a higher plane".
